# I want use Facebook Connect/user creation but use a custom username.

Tags: facebook, blackberry, buddypress

I want use Facebook Connect/user creation but use a custom username. My site is a Blackberry website and All my members use their BBpin as username. Is their any Buddypress/WPMU can do this? or a trick to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just prompt the user to choose a username the first time they authorise your app? When they log in subsequently via Facebook you can still lookup your own database to see what username they chose last time